# Was there a more appropriate community to post this to?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm having an issue found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/956870/why-cant-i-connect-to-this-site-via-https). Despite getting views and even an upvote, I'm curious if the community overall isn't ideal in spite of having seemingly appropriate tags. The comments are basically just asking me things I've already gone over in my post which I simply explain in a more verbose fashion.

Where else would I post this or ask for a migration? I plan on giving it a bounty tomorrow, if nothing else.

To add some detail, I'm having an SSL issue with a particular site and that one site only (and only it's SSL'd portion) after having upgraded to Windows 10. I've reached out and done what I can think of to verify it's my problem versus a problem in Windows or their site. I've posted an openssl output to try to show what's going wrong. I'm curious if the Superuser community was the right place for this.

Comment: Rather than forcing us to go to your other question to find out what you're talking about, could you summarize the issue here? We can certainly go there to get more specifics but we should be able to see generally what you're looking for without going there.

Comment: I'll edit my question.

Comment: Tags never define the scope of a site, the help center and meta sites does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You literally asked that question 14 hours ago.

A single upvote plus some good feedback from your fellow users probably means that the question is valid for Super User. It is for these type of people anyways:

> ...for computer enthusiasts and power users

Windows 10 should be a valid topic for Super User, hence the upvote and no one commenting on where else you should post your question. It is perfect where it is right now. Even though you are using code, don't post this on Stack Overflow as this is mainly a problem with Windows 10, not the code I believe.

Now you really don't need a bounty for the question yet in my opinion. You posted the question today in UTC time and received good feedback. Wait a few days, maybe a week and then decide whether you really need that bounty. Most questions will a day or two to get answered, maybe three or four if it's difficult.

Comment: I'll try to be patient. I guess I'm used to Stack Overflow where answers and communication generally come quickly to well written questions. The delay had me questioning if I had written it well enough, posted it in the right spot, etc.

Comment: Stack Overflow has so many users, answers will come quick. But newer sites will take longer to get an answer if the question is of good quality.